# assign output of memcache command to a variable in shell/bash script

Tags: bash, shell, memcached

I have a bash script with this code

```
echo -e 'get mykey\r' | nc localhost 11211
```

when I run the script I get this output on the terminal :

```
VALUE mykey 0 1
0
END
```

But instead of printing it on the terminal I want to assign the output of the command `'get mykey\r' | nc localhost 11211` to a variable in my bash script.

Also when I use `echo -e` it prints `VALUE mykey 0 1` and `END` which I don't want in my variable.

So the expected output is that the variable should contain only the value of the corresponding key i.e in this case the variable should contain the value 0 (can be anything depending on the key which is being get) only.

What I tried :

```
output = 'get mykey\r' | nc localhost 11211
echo $output
```

but this gives `output: command not found` error

How do I do it?

Comment: `'get mykey\r'` is a string, not a command. The commands in your question are `echo` and `nc`.  You can't have white space around `=` in shell, the syntax to use for assignment is `x=7`, not `x = 7`. Try `output=$(echo -e 'get mykey\r' | nc localhost 11211); echo "$output"`.

Comment: thank you it works now. I want remove VALUE mykey 0 1 and END from the output. How to do that?

Comment: You could pipe it to `awk 'NR==2'`.

Comment: how? i have no idea about awk.tried searching it on google but didn't get it how to use it in my code

Comment: I put it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do:

```
output=$(echo -e 'get mykey\r' | nc localhost 11211 | awk 'NR==2')
echo "$output"
```

but check the man page for `nc` to see if it has any options to control what it outputs.

Comment: btw the code   if [ $output = 0 ]
 then
 echo "output is 0"
 else
 echo "output is not 0 "
 fi    always returns output is not 0 even if the output is 0. what's wrong here? Is the output not a number?

Comment: That's a completely different question and that code contains syntax errors. Ask a new question if you want help with that or just google "how to test a variable in shell" or similar.